# Python Prime Numbers Code Problem

Tags: primes

I was trying to write my own code for primes in Python. I know that code already exists, but I am doing this to challenge my knowledge and make my own solution. I was wondering if any of you guys would tell me what's wrong with it.

```
factor_list = [ ]

def integer_test(x):

    if type(x) == int:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def factor_checker(x):

    count = 0
    y = x
    while count <= y:
        print(count)
        count += 1
        if integer_test(x / count) == True:
            factor_list.append(count)

factor_checker(45)

print(factor_list)
```

When I try to input a number for factor checker and then look at the factor list, I just get an empty list. What is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question is off-topic here: we deal with computer *science* questions, not programming questions (see our [FAQ]). Your question might be on-topic on [SO] or perhaps [codereview.se] (but please choose one: don't post to both).

Comment: My mistake! :) Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get an empty list. See [this](https://ideone.com/GRolwJ). However you won't get the desired results because in python `int` divided by `int` is always `int`.  You may want to try this:

```
import math

factor_list = [ ]

def integer_test(x):

    if math.floor(x) == math.ceil(x):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def factor_checker(x):

    count = 0
    y = x
    while count <= y:
        print(count)
        count += 1
        if integer_test(1.0 * x / count) == True:
            factor_list.append(count)

factor_checker(45)

print(factor_list)
```

In this code `x/count` is a double. So the `integer_test` will only return true if it's ceiling and floor return the same number i.e the integer itself.